# A sum of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am looking for a proof or a reference for the following
( apparent ) combinatorial identity:

$$
\sum_{i = s}^{s+t}\left(\,{-1}\,\right)^{\, i}{i \choose s}
{s \choose i - t}
=
\left(\,{-1}\,\right)^{s + t},\quad\mbox{where}\ s\geq t\geq 0\
\mbox{are integers}
$$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is one of many identities that boil down to Chu-Vandermonde convolution after a sequence of transformations (using symmetry and upper negation). To wit: Replace $\dbinom{i}{s}$ by $\dbinom{i}{i-s}$ and apply upper negation to the latter term. Replace $\dbinom{s}{i-t}$ by $\dbinom{s}{s-\left(i-t\right)} = \dbinom{s}{t-\left(i-s\right)}$. The left hand side then becomes $\left(-1\right)^s \sum\limits_{i=s}^{s+t} \dbinom{-s-1}{i-s} \dbinom{s}{t-\left(i-s\right)}$. Substitute $k$ for $i-s$ in the sum; then ...

Comment: ... the sum simplifies to $\dbinom{-1}{t}$ by Chu-Vandermonde convolution. But $\dbinom{-1}{t} = \left(-1\right)^t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint of @darijgrinberg is valuable and deserves an answer by its own.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{q=s}^{s+t}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^q\binom{q}{s}\binom{s}{q-t}}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^t(-1)^{q+s}\binom{q+s}{q}\binom{s}{q+s-t}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^s\sum_{q=0}^t\binom{-s-1}{q}\binom{s}{t-q}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^s\binom{-1}{t}\tag{3}\\
> &=(-1)^s\frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-t)}{t!}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^{s+t}}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the index to start with $q=0$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identities $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

Answer (score 2):

We seek to verify that

$$\sum_{q=s}^{s+t} (-1)^q {q\choose s} {s\choose q-t}
= (-1)^{s+t}$$

where $s\ge t\ge 0.$ The LHS is

$$\sum_{q=0}^{t} (-1)^{s+q} {s+q\choose s} {s\choose s+q-t}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{t} (-1)^{s+q} {s+q\choose s} {s\choose t-q}
\\ = (-1)^s [z^t] (1+z)^s
\sum_{q=0}^{t} (-1)^{q} {s+q\choose s} z^q.$$

The coefficient extractor controls the range of the sum and we may write

$$(-1)^s [z^t] (1+z)^s
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^{q} {s+q\choose s} z^q
\\ = (-1)^s [z^t] (1+z)^s
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{s+1}}
\\ = (-1)^s [z^t] \frac{1}{1+z} 
= (-1)^s (-1)^t = (-1)^{s+t}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Answer verified. (+1)